# struggling to understand what is casuing this key error exception

Tags: python

For my learning and devlopment I have decided to pick up prgramming and decided to pick up python I have started with a colour check application using the following [tutorial](https://data-flair.training/blogs/project-in-python-colour-detection/comment-page-1/)

However whenever I run the actiavtion command to open my image I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    PathToImage = args['colour_select']
KeyError: 'colour_select'
```

I am relatively new to python so this may not be the only error in my code. I am mostly confused as to how this is heppening.

My code full code:

```
# imports
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import argparse

# variable declaration
clicked = False
red = blue = green = xpos = ypos = 0

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-i', required=True, help="PathToImage")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
PathToImage = args['colour_select']

img = cv2.imread(PathToImage)

# read csv file
index = ["colour", "colour_name", "hex", "R", "G", "B"]
csv = pd.read('colours.csv', names=index, header=None)

cv2.namedWindow('colour_select')
cv2.setMouseCallback('colour_select', draw_function)


def draw_function(event, x, y, flags, parameters):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        global blue, green, red, xpos, ypos, clicked
        clicked = True
        xpos = x
        ypos = y
        blue, green, red = img[x, y]
        blue = int(blue)
        green = int(green)
        red = int(red)


def getColourName(red, green, blue):
    minimum = 10000
    for i in range(len(csv)):
        distance = abs(red - int(csv.loc[i, "Red"])) + abs(green - int(csv.loc[i, "Green"])) + abs(
            blue - int(csv.loc[i, "Blue"]))
        if (distance <= minimum):
            minimum = distance
            ColourName = csv.loc[i, "colour_name"]
        return ColourName


while (1):
    cv2.imshow("colour_select", img)
    if (clicked):
        cv2.rectangle(img, (20, 20), (750, 60), (blue, green, red), -1)

        text = getColourName(red, green, blue) + ' R=' + str(red) + 'G=' + str(green) + ' B+' + str(blue)

        cv2.putText(img, text, (50, 50), 2, 0.8, (0, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        if (red, blue, green >= 600):
            cv2.putText(img, text, (50, 50), 2, 0.8, (0, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        clicked = False

    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As always any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems to me that 'colour_select' is not a key the args object, which I assume is a dictionary. You could easily debug with a if 'colour_select' in args: print("not here"), or you could also run a print(list(args.keys())) to see all the keys.

Comment: Well, `args` is constructed from the `ArgumentParser`, with only one argument defined, so I'd expect `args` to only have one element, `'i'`; there's no `add_argument('--colour_select', ...)` so there won't be a `'colour_select'` element in `args`.

Comment: As a guess, are you perhaps inconsistently using the spellings "colour" and "color"?

Answer (score 0):

I started by isolating the cause of the issue to

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-i', required=True, help="PathToImage")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
PathToImage = args['colour_select']
```

I put that code in "myscript.py" and ran it; specifically I tried

```
python myscript.py -i "hello"
```

I was able to reproduce the issue. To figure out the cause, I added a print statement

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-i', required=True, help="PathToImage")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
print(args)
PathToImage = args['colour_select']
```

What that showed on the command line was `{'i': 'hello'}`

If you want the key to be `colour_select`, then you should use that as the argument string

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-colour_select', required=True, help="PathToImage")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
if 'colour_select' not in args.keys():
    print("ERROR!")
PathToImage = args['colour_select']
print('PathToImage =',PathToImage)
```